# retrieve comments made by a facebook Page

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

How to get the comments made by a facebook page for example this https://www.facebook.com/nauhotels, with the code below only getting geting general information, so what format is the Url retrive the comments made by this Page?

---

```
$Page_ID = 'https://www.facebook.com/nauhotels';
$Comment_ID= '';

//$facebookurl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$Page_ID.'/feed?&access_token='.$Access_Token;
$facebookurl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$Page_ID.'/comments?limit=10&access_token='.$Access_Token;


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $facebookurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$facebookurlResults = curl_exec($ch);
$facebookinfo = json_decode($facebookurlResults);

var_dump($facebookinfo);
```

---

the json returned

```
   object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'id' => string '893083347383161' (length=15)
  public 'about' => string 'O Presente e o Futuro, agora, sÃ£o NAU!
NAU Ã© o novo grupo hoteleiro portuguÃªs que eleva o paÃ­s ao melhor de si prÃ³prio!
' (length=125)
  public 'can_post' => boolean false
  public 'category' => string 'Company' (length=7)
  public 'checkins' => int 0
  public 'company_overview' => string 'O Presente e o Futuro, agora, sÃ£o NAU!

NAU Ã© o novo grupo hoteleiro portuguÃªs que eleva o paÃ­s ao melhor de si prÃ³prio!

NAU Ã© no Algarve, no Alentejo, no Douro e em Lisboa. NAU Ã© energÃ©tico, revitalizante e relaxante. NAU Ã© vida!

E a vida sÃ£o momentos â€¦ mais marcantes, mais saborosos, mais vibrantes, mais poderosos! 
SÃ£o todos esses momentos da sua vida que queremos acompanhar. Seja num quarto de um dos nossos 10 hotÃ©is, seja Ã  mesa, num spa ou num campo de golfe. Aqui!
Aqui e como atÃ© ag'... (length=941)
  public 'cover' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'cover_id' => string '937301482961347' (length=15)
      public 'offset_x' => int 0
      public 'offset_y' => int 0
      public 'source' => string 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/11034911_937301482961347_3077070950635186563_n.jpg?oh=146c903fee3bacd00e469c00e8e8c330&oe=557DB6A4&__gda__=1433612610_dbaa0c67f0131c5be822bded8d0c46ae' (length=223)
      public 'id' => string '937301482961347' (length=15)
  public 'has_added_app' => boolean false
  public 'is_community_page' => boolean false
  public 'is_published' => boolean true
  public 'likes' => int 7113
  public 'link' => string 'https://www.facebook.com/nauhotels' (length=34)
  public 'name' => string 'NAU Hotels & Resorts' (length=20)
  public 'talking_about_count' => int 170
  public 'username' => string 'nauhotels' (length=9)
  public 'website' => string 'http://www.nauhotels.com' (length=24)
  public 'were_here_count' => int 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

> /{page-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this page.
>
> /{page-id}/tagged shows the posts that this page was tagged in and the 'posts to page'

If you want to get the comments, you would have to use a specific Post-ID:

`/{post-id}/comments`

Make sure you understand the difference between posts and comments.

Comment: Thanks needed to get the id of the Page by the json that had retrived previously,then send the new url `$facebookurl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/893083347383161/posts?&access_token='.$Access_Token;`